# JavaScript me convierte una fecha a un número y deseo mantenerlo como fecha

Tags: php, javascript

```
<?php
$consulta2="SELECT fecha FROM cumples WHERE id='$reg[cumples]'";
$resultado2=mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta2) or die(mysqli_error($conexion));
$reg2=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado2) or die(mysqli_error($conexion));
?>
<a onclick='preguntar3(<?php echo $reg2[0]; ?>)'><img src='cumple.png' height='17'></a>
<script>
function preguntar3(fecha)
{
    alert(fecha);
}
</script>
```

Deseo que la fecha que obtengo con la consulta hecha en mysqli me salga con una alarte em javascript pero en formato de fecha y no me sale. Me sale un número que no comprendo.

Comment: Te hacen faltan las comillas, deberia de verse así `preguntar3("<?php echo $reg2[0]; ?>")`

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Lo que estas intentando mostrar en el `alert` es un string, por que lo te hace falta añadirle las comillas. En este caso comillas dobles por que ya estas usando comillas simples en el atributo `onclick`

```php
<?php
$consulta2="SELECT fecha FROM cumples WHERE id='$reg[cumples]'";
$resultado2=mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta2) or die(mysqli_error($conexion));
$reg2=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado2) or die(mysqli_error($conexion));
?>
<a onclick='preguntar3("<?php echo $reg2[0]; ?>")'><img src='cumple.png' height='17'></a>
<script>
function preguntar3(fecha)
{
    alert(fecha);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!